# How to align right parts of the text in select option list?

Tags: html, dropdown, html-select

How to align to right parts of the text in select option list

```html
<option>Income1       250</option>
<option>Income2       100</option>
<option>Income3       150</option>
```

Comment: what you want to do? and where is your code...?

Comment: I want to see Income text to aligned left and Numbers to aligned right when I open the dropdown list in html.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't possible do that, maybe if you use a placeholder aligned to the right, and the actual option aligned to the left...

However if you don't mind having two different options in a row of the dropdown, you can use this jQuery plugin (plus normal jQuery library).

https://github.com/shawnchin/jquery-gentleSelect

And utilise it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selector').gentleSelect(({
        rows: 2,
        itemWidth: 50,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to each of the elements... such as

option class=“name1”

Then call it using .name1 in the css file. Once you’ve done this you can use ‘float’ and choose where you want it to sit... either left right or centre.